# How to remove a field from an array using aggregate on MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
    {Crs:{[
       {Cr: {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
            "Number" : 400,
            "Page" : 24,
            "DC" : "NE",
        }},
       {Cr: {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
            "Number" : 300,
            "Page" : 14,
            "DC" : "100",
        }},
 ]}}
```

I have this data that i model using aggregate and I would like to know how can i remove "DC" field from all elements of the array using aggregate.

```
  >db.crs.aggregate(
    [
        {$group : {_id : null, crs : {$push : {cr : "$$ROOT"}}}},
        {$project : {_id : 0}}
    ]
)
```

This is what did to model that data.
I think its something related with $project.

Comment: Is that even valid JSON?

Comment: @chridam I'm really new in this so i didnt use any validate method. I just modeled the data that I imported from a csv file using aggregate.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the actual JSON output that you get when you run the query `db.crs.find({}).limit(2).pretty()`?

Comment: @chridam Its kinda hard to do that because is this not my actual work, its just an example to understand better how this works.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your document is not a valid JSON schema. You might reconsider the following schema for that particular document.

```
{
    Crs:[
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
            "Number" : 400,
            "Page" : 24,
            "DC" : "NE"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
            "Number" : 300,
            "Page" : 14,
            "DC" : "100"
        }
    ]
}
```

Having above schema, you can easily remove **DC** field using [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset) aggregate operator.

```
db.crs.aggregate([{$unset: 'Crs.DC'}]);
```